# Playlist folder creation via Spotify Apps API

Tags: playlist, spotify

Spotify Apps API Documentation defines a [Playlist](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/reference/c49e02a392.html) model, but no model for Playlist folders (folders that have playlists nested within them). I know the spotify core object has a `core.library.createPlaylistGroup()` function but of course this is off-limits for any Apps API development.

Any ideas on if it'd be possible to create playlist folders via API methods?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, there is no way in the current Spotify API to manage playlists folders.

Related: [Access playlist folder structure from Spotify app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118062/access-playlist-folder-structure-from-spotify-app)

Comment: Confirmed: "Folders are not returned through the Web API at the moment, nor can be created using it." - https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/working-with-playlists/#folders