# Access playlist folder structure from Spotify app?

Tags: html, api, web-applications, spotify

Using the Spotify Apps API, it is possible to access the playlists of a user. But is it also possible to access the folder structure holding the playlists? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's unfortunately not possible at this time.

If anyone is wondering what folders are, here's a folder named Test. Simply drag playlists to the folder to add them to it.

[image]